# Start a keyframes at scrolling and when element appears on page with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, dom

I have a CSS animation for progress bars that fill up. I would like to use Javascript to trigger the animation when scrolling over it and when it appears on screen.

It works when the page loads and not when you get to it. Which means that it is already finished before seeing the result as it is at the bottom of the page. I tried things but it doesn't work.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('SkillBar');

function checkScroll() {
  const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  elements.forEach(element => {
    const position = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (position.top <= windowHeight * 0.8) {
      element.classList.add('.Skill-HTML');
    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll);
```

```css
.Skill-HTML {
  width: 90%;
  animation: Animate-HTML 6s;
  -webkit-animation: Animate-HTML 6s;
  -moz-animation: Animate-HTML 6s;
  -o-animation: Animate-HTML 6s;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #D741A7;
}

@keyframes Animate-HTML {
  from {
    width: 10px;
  }
  to {
    width: 90%
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes Animate-HTML {
  from {
    width: 10px;
  }
  to {
    width: 90%
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes Animate-HTML {
  from {
    width: 10px;
  }
  to {
    width: 90%
  }
}

@-o-keyframes Animate-HTML {
  from {
    width: 10px;
  }
  to {
    width: 90%
  }
}

.Skill-CSS {
  animation: Animate-CSS 5s;
  -webkit-animation: Animate-CSS 5s;
  -moz-animation: Animate-CSS 5s;
  -o-animation: Animate-CSS 5s;
  width: 90%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #3A1772;
}

@keyframes Animate-CSS {
  from {
    width: 10px;
  }
  to {
    width: 90%
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes Animate-CSS {
  from {
    width: 10px;
  }
  to {
    width: 90%
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes Animate-CSS {
  from {
    width: 10px;
  }
  to {
    width: 90%
  }
}

@-o-keyframes Animate-CSS {
  from {
    width: 10px;
  }
  to {
    width: 70%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="SkillBar">
  <div class="Skill-HTML">
    <span class="Skill-Area ">HTML</span>
    <span class="PercentText ">90%</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="SkillBar">
  <div class="Skill-CSS">
    <span class="Skill-Area ">CSS/SCSS</span>
    <span class="PercentText ">90%</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For future reference, please put your code in a snippet. That way you don't need to escape all the angle brackets/quotes with a backslash and everything will be correctly formatted